# Isolate frequencies of audio context using the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm experimenting with the WebAudio API and am attempting to build an analyser that a user can interact with and ultimately turn on and off different frequencies within the music to isolate different beats within the track, i.e bass, kick etc.

I'm visualising the frequency data using the Canvas, and would like the user to be able to highlight parts of the visualisation, and in-turn muting frequencies.

By default the visualisation would look like this and the user would hear all frequencies.

[image]

But when the user selects several bars, the greyed out ones would mute the related frequencies:

[image]

My thinking is can I reverse-engineer the frequencyData array and essentially mute the associated frequencies?

** Update **

So I've been playing around by adding several `biquadFilter`s with a type of `notch` in series, and then adjusting their frequency and Q values. This does sort of help isolate pats of the music, but not exactly how I want. This is the code I'm using so far...

```
const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(element);
const biquadFilter1 = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
const biquadFilter2 = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
const biquadFilter3 = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

biquadFilter1.connect(analyser);
biquadFilter2.connect(analyser);
biquadFilter3.connect(analyser);
source
    .connect(biquadFilter1)
    .connect(biquadFilter2)
    .connect(biquadFilter3);
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

I'm not sure if I've set this up correctly, but it does allow me to very roughly manipulate the frequencies, but it feels like there is no accurate science to doing it this way.

Is what I'm attempting possible, and if so, any suggestions are really appreciated :)

Comment: can't you just [].slice() the data in the canvas drawing part? you can `Math.max.apply(0, arrData)` to re-scale it JIT if needed...

Comment: Yes, but that won't disable the audio frequencies that they represent

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is a **band pass** filter.

> A band-pass filter (also bandpass filter, BPF) is a device that passes
>   frequencies within a certain range and rejects (attenuates)
>   frequencies outside that range. 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter

And we are lucky, the web audio api provide it via the **BiquadFilterNode**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode

So, based on the demo code provided, to apply a band pass filter at the 400Hz frequency range to an html audio player.

The html audio element must be created by js then inserted into the DOM, or it won't works with the web audio api.

```
 <div id="hello"></div>

 <script>
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    // Create new player 
    var a = document.createElement("audio");
    // Give a source song
    a.src = "vorbis.ogg";
    // Show the controls
    a.setAttribute("controls", "");
    // Append to the DOM
    hello.appendChild(a);

    // Player now ready for the web audio api
    var mediaElement = a;

    //set up the different audio nodes we will use for the app

    var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    var biquadFilter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();

    // connect the nodes together

    source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);
    source.connect(biquadFilter);
    biquadFilter.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    // Manipulate the Biquad filter

    biquadFilter.type = "bandpass";
    biquadFilter.frequency.value = 400;
    biquadFilter.gain.value = 25;
</script>
```

The *biquadFilter.frequency.value* represent the center of the range frequencies. The range expands with the gain value.

This filters can be chained just like this example with some other **GainNode**, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode

In a similar way, using two filters, a lowpass and a highpass, for the range 1000hz to 1500hz.

> ```
> <div id="hello"></div>
> <script>
> var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext)()
> var a = document.createElement("audio")
> a.src = "vorbis.ogg"
> a.setAttribute("controls", "")
> hello.appendChild(a)
>
> var mediaElement = a
>
> var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain()
> var lowpass = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter()
> var highpass = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter()
>
> source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement)
> source.connect(lowpass)
> lowpass.connect(highpass)
> highpass.connect(gainNode)
> gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)
>
> lowpass.type = "lowpass"
> lowpass.frequency.value = 1000
> lowpass.gain.value = -1
> highpass.type = "highpass"
> highpass.frequency.value = 1500
> highpass.gain.value = -1 
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Can I achieve the same result using `createMediaElementSource` rather than `createMediaStreamSource`, as I'm currently using the native Audio element and playing an MP3

Comment: So I tried simply replacing that line with `const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(element);`, but can now no longer hear any output

Comment: Yes. But it needs to be created by js first or it won't works (spent time to understand this..)  `a = document.createElement("audio"); var context = new AudioContext();
var mediaElement = a;
var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement)` You need to populate your audio element src and append it to the dom with javascript. It doesn't work on static html

Comment: Demo code updated to show how to use `createMediaElementSource` (tested working)

Comment: in this way you are "muting" frequencies in the range 1000hz to 1500hz. correct?

Comment: On the 2nd example, it's the other way around, leaving the 1000-1500hz untouched, but filtering others ranges, this is not fully suppressing. There is an extra params in web audio filters called the Q, not shown here. It modify the depth of the filters.

Comment: As stated on MDN, you need to use the attribute Q for specfying the range of bandpass filter.

Comment: Tx for underlining, yes the Q factor has some interesting audio rendering, but this is not the band range of a filter: It is the damping factor, as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor .In electronic, this is like varying a capacitor capacity.

Comment: @NVRM - according to the MDN the `gain` value for a bandpass is unused - so what is the right way to infact determine the "width" of the bandpass frequency filter?

Answer (score 0):

You’re working with audio, so what you need is a band-pass filter. That will allow you to play only certain frequencies.

I can see you’re already using FFT to get the frequencies. From there, you have two options. One is to remove the frequencies you want from that array obtained after you do the FFT. Then, in order to get the sound you need the signal in the time domain, so you will need an Inverse FFT. The other option is to make your filter in the time domain, and then make convolution with the original signal.

I’m not posting code since I’ve just made this in C, but I’m pretty sure there are many libraries to do these operations easily (Convolution/IFFT).
:)

Comment: Removing the frequencies and doing an IFFT won't work. You don't have the phase information.  And even if you did have the phase information, it won't work, because that operation isn't band-limited, so you'll introduce aliasing artifacts in the output.

Comment: so, what do you propose?

Comment: The problem is a bit under-specified, but maybe a bunch of notch filters?  Or fake a linear phase to go with the FFT, use a design program to get an impulse response and use that in a convolver? (Which you suggested.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @RaymondToy I've had a stab at adding the notch filters, and also updated the question so it hopefully makes more sense. If you have the time to give any more direction to this I'd really appreciate it :)