# Record Low Volume Input from Microphone using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Web Audio API to record low volume input from a mircophone. So essentially I'm looking to record in low frequencies or decibels that start from 0Hz to around 100Hz.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

So this is what I've got so far:

```
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    }
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }, function(stream) {
        var ctx = new AudioContext();
        var source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var gainNode = ctx.createGain();

        source.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
        document.getElementById('volume').onchange = function() {
            gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
        };

        gainNode.gain.value = document.getElementById('volume').value;

        new Audio().play();

    }, function(e) {
        alert(e);
});

    // For the demo only:
    document.getElementById('volume').onchange = function() {
        alert('Please provide access to the microhone before using this.');
    }
```

This is HTML control:

```
Volume: <input type=range id=volume min=0 max=100 value=50 step=0.01/>
```

From what I can tell, all I am doing with this code is lowering the output volume level from the microphone.

As I said, I am trying to capture low volume input from 0Hz to 100Hz.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for. This question is [asking for a solution without attempting to show any work](https://can-i-haz.codes/). Please provide some code to help us work with you to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Constantin. I fixed my question up a bit to be better suited for answers.

Comment: From what I can see...you can't set this, what you have to do is record the sound and process it for low volume input

Comment: Are you saying you basically want to record the input audio from 0 Hz to 100 Hz, ignoring all higher frequencies?

Comment: Yes. I want to record just low volume, low frequency sounds

Comment: Frequency is not related to volume. Maybe try to implement a [bandpass filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48528432/5156280).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want record just the frequencies between 0 and 100 Hz, use one or more  [BiquadFilterNodes](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#biquadfilternode) or an [IIRFilterNode](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#iirfilternode) to implement a lowpass filter with a cutoff of 100 Hz or so.

Generally, it's up to you to figure out the right filter, but perhaps this [filter design page](http://rtoy.github.io/webaudio-hacks/more/filter-design/filter-design.html) will be helpful. Use at your own risk!

Comment: The BiQuadFilter was what I was looking for. Lets you set HighPass and LowPass filters at whatever frequency you want. Thanks for the post.

Comment: Fantastic!  But note that a single BiquadFilterNode may not have a sharp enough cutoff, so you might need to cascade several or use an IIRFilterNode to have a sharp enough cutoff.